# Adding Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add a Marker to my Google Map and I can not get it to appear.

I'm calling a function, `createMarkers(x, y)` and passing two strings in from an aspx page.

Here's the createMarkers function:

```
function createMarkers(x, y) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
console.log(latlng);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: "User location"
}); 

};
```

The marker doesn't appear on the map and no errors are printed into the console.

I've logged my variable `latlng` to the console to inspect and this is what it shows:

```
O
ab: 51.486091
cb: -0.05983800000001338
__proto__: O
```

I've looked through the google documentation on Markers [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=nl-NL#Markers) and the code I've got looks good enough to work.

One last thing, I've also tried adding the coordinates directly to the latlng variable instead of using my x & y parameters. This didn't work either.

I guess I'm missing something pretty obvious. As always any help will be greatly appreciated!

JA

Comment: make sure that 'map' is declared on a global level, otherwise the function may not be able to access it. If that's not it, post a live like to code demonstrating the problem so we can debug it.

Comment: Could be a bit tricky to set up a fiddle as I'm using asp.net master pages and code behind pages. I definitely declare map on a global level but I've also tried removing that and declaring it locally in the function which doesn't work either.

Comment: No, declaring it locally wouldn't, since it has to refer to the map that you've initialized. Another common problem people have is that they set-up a global variable map, but then declare a local variable var map= in the initializing function. I don't think we can help you much more at this point without seeing your code. I would render the map using your asp.net code and then copy and paste the javascript into a jsFiddle. Only needs to be a subset that replicates the problem.

Comment: I'll strip it all out tonight and get a bare bones example. I'm obviously missing something pretty simple, perhaps I'll see it when I get everything out. Thanks for taking the time to look at it with me. JA

Answer (score 0):

These are the function that I use to render the map and add markers:

```
function renderMap(mapContainer) {
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.645004, -79.380707),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    window.map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);
}

function addMarkerToMap(lat, long, titleText) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        title: titleText,
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried using your `addMarkerToMap` function but get exactly the same results.

Comment: Perhaps try adding `marker.setMap(map);` with your original code as outlined in the Maps API docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays).

Comment: I had that in originally, it still didn't work! Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

The function as it is should work.

Assuming the map-variable is available and points to a map-object:

Adding a marker to a map will not set the viewport of the map to contain the marker, could it be that  the marker is present, but outside of the viewport?

Try adding this to the end of `createMarkers()` :

```
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I know roughly where the marker should be and it's just not appearing. I'll give it a try later just to be sure though! Thanks for your help.